# Changing autocomplete dropdown items css when down arrow is pressed

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, css-selectors

Iam trying to fix the styling of jQ.autocomplete item. When i hover over the suggested item the css is correct. But whenever i press the "key down" the styling changes to something else. 
How do i do this?

example with mouse hover:
[image]

example with down arrow:
[image]

This is what i have for the hover styling:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete li:hover a
{
border:none;
background-color: #6695CF;
background-image: none;
}
```

what ive tried, along with 15 other solutions:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete li:focus a
{
border:none;
background-color: #6695CF;
background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a running snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {


 font-weight: bold;
 border:none;
 background-color: #6695CF;
 background-image: none;
 color: white;

}
```

Did the trick.